# Create organic group programmatically

Tags: drupal-7, organic-groups

I'm looking for a way to create an organic group in code.
On the web i find manny resources on how to add a node to a group etc, but not how to create a group itself.

I have done it using the drupal interface, but this isn't very portable. I have tried using the features module, although i found that had to many issues. Missing fields etc.

Through the interface you create a group by making a new contenttype, and then under the tab 'organic groups' you select 'group'

I know how to create a content type in code

```
$type = array(
  'type' => 'Termbase2type',
  'name' => t('Termbase2name'),
  'base' => 'node_content',
  'custom' => 1,
  'modified' => 1,
  'locked' => 0,
  'title_label' => 'Termbase2',
  'description' => 's a database consisting of concept-oriented terminological entries (or ‘concepts’) and related information, usually in multilingual format. Entries may include any of the following additional information: a definition; source or context of the term; subject area, domain, or industry; grammatical information (verb, noun, etc.); notes; usage label (figurative, American English, formal, etc.); author (‘created by’), creation/modification date (‘created/modified at’); verification status (‘verified’ or ‘approved’ terms), and an ID. A termbase allows for the systematic management of approved or verified terms and is a powerful tool for promoting consistency in terminology. *wiki',
  'og_group_type' => 1,
  'og_private' => 0,
  'og_register' => 0,
  'og_directory' => 0,
  'og_selective' => 3,
);

$type = node_type_set_defaults($type);
node_type_save($type);
node_add_body_field($type);
```

but i can't find any clue as to how to set the content type as a group, so it can have group members.

Comment: Tell me you solved this one.. I'm looking at this right now. I'm thinking the devel module would be enlightening?

Comment: No, in the end i end up writting some code for my specific needs, ignoring the OG modules.

Answer (score 1):

This worked:

```
// get existing content types
$content_types = node_type_get_types();
$t = get_t();

// create the currency CT
$type_name = 'cc';
if (!array_key_exists($type_name, $content_types)) {
    //  Create the type definition array.
    $type = array(
        'type' => $type_name,
        'name' => $t('Community Currency'),
        'base' => 'node_content',
        'description' => $t('A community that trades in a virtual currency.'),
        'custom' => 1,
        'modified' => 1,
        'locked' => 0,
    );
    $type = node_type_set_defaults($type);
    node_type_save($type);
    //  Add a body field.
    node_add_body_field($type);


    variable_set('og_group_type_' . $type_name, TRUE);

    og_ui_node_type_save($type_name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use Drupal's [drupal_form_submit() function](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/drupal_form_submit/7) to [programmatically submit the necessary forms](http://brianfisher.name/content/programmatically-submit-form-drupal-7). It may be a bit tedious and not be as straightforward as using an API, but it should work.